# edit a table's cells by clicking an edit button with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't know the problem with my code, I'm trying to make an editable cell when you click edit it edits the cell plus instead of the edit and delete buttons there should appear a save button that works, (I have a problem with that it doesn't work), here is my html code of my table:

```js
function deleteButtons(btns, tdBtns) {
  for (let index = 0; index < btns.length; index += index) {
    tdBtns.removeChild(btns[index]);
  }
}

function createButtons(bool, td) {
  if (bool) {
    var Edit = document.createElement('input');
    Edit.type = "button";
    Edit.value = "Edit";
    Edit.setAttribute('onclick', 'Edit(this)');
    td.appendChild(Edit);

    var Delete = document.createElement('input');
    Delete.type = "button";
    Delete.setAttribute('onclick', 'Delete(this)');
    Delete.value = "Delete";
    td.appendChild(Delete);

  } else {

    var Save = document.createElement('input');
    Save.type = "button";
    Save.value = "Save";
    Save.setAttribute('onclick', 'Save(this)');
    td.appendChild(Save);
  }
}

function Add() {
  var p1 = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  const row1 = document.getElementById("row1");
  var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");



  //insert row beginning or end
  var element = document.createElement("tr");
  var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
  table.appendChild(element);

  if (document.getElementById('input1').checked) {
    table.insertBefore(element, table.firstElementChild);

  } else if (document.getElementById('input2').checked) {
    table.lastElementChild.after(element);
  }

  var case1 = document.createElement("td");
  case1.innerHTML = p1;
  element.appendChild(case1);

  var case2 = document.createElement("td");
  element.appendChild(case2);
  createButtons(true, case2);
}


//delete:
function Delete(element) {
  element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode.parentNode);
}


//Edit:

function Edit(element) {

  const row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  const tdList = row.children;

  for (let index = 0; index < tdList.length - 1; index++) {
    const element = tdList[index];
    var str = element.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.id = "edit" + (index + 1).toString();
    input.value = str;
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
    element.appendChild(input);



  }
  const tdBtns = tdList[1];
  const btns = tdBtns.children;
  deleteButtons(btns, tdBtns);
  createButtons(false, tdBtns);
}


function Save(element) {
  const row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  const tdList = row.children;

  /* const edit = [
      ['edit1'],
      ['edit2']
  ]; */

  const edit = [];
  for (let index = 0; index <= 1; index++) {
    edit[index] = document.getElementById("edit" + (index + 1).toString()).value;
    if (edit[index] == "") {
      alert("You must not keep textboxes empty");
      var empty = true;
    }
  }

  if (!empty) {
    for (let index = 0; index < tdList.length - 1; index++) {
      tdList[index].removeChild(tdList[index].children[0]);
      var text = document.createTextNode(edit[index]);
      tdList[index].appendChild(text);
    }
    const tdBtns = tdList[1];
    const btns = tdBtns.children;
    deleteButtons(btns, tdBtns);
    createButtons(true, tdBtns);

  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Table</h1>
<div id="principal">
  <div id="cntr"><input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Element to add.">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="Add()"><br><br></div>
  <form id="frm">
    Add :
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input1"> at the beginning
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input2"> at the end
  </form><br>
  <table id="MyTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="row1">
        <td id="name_row1">Element 1 </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" onclick="Edit(this)">
          <input type="button" value="Supprimer" onclick="Delete(this)">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Don't use inline `on*` handlers in HTML. Use `addEventListener()` instead

Comment: `I have a problem with that it doesn't work`: please be specific; how is it not working? What's the actual result (vs expected)? Is there an error in your console?

Comment: when I click the save button its not saving the input but the code makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

The console is your friend. When you try to edit a td, it clearly warns you that you're trying to access "value" from a null object. It's to do with this part of the Save() function:

```
for (let index = 0; index <= 1; index++) {
    edit[index] = document.getElementById("edit" + (index + 1).toString()).value;
```

The big issue here is where does `index <= 1` come from? In theory you're looping through the `td`s in the row, right? Right now there's only one, and I see no way to add more for now.

So it tries to access the value property of an element with id "edit2" in the second iteration of the for loop. "edit2" doesn't exist, hence the error.

Funny thing is that the solution is already in your code. In your Edit() function you loop through the number of row children, with `index < tdList.length - 1`. Well, simply use that in your Save() function and it works fine!

You'll see it working in the snippet:

```js
function deleteButtons(btns, tdBtns) {
  for (let index = 0; index < btns.length; index += index) {
    tdBtns.removeChild(btns[index]);
  }
}

function createButtons(bool, td) {
  if (bool) {
    var Edit = document.createElement('input');
    Edit.type = "button";
    Edit.value = "Edit";
    Edit.setAttribute('onclick', 'Edit(this)');
    td.appendChild(Edit);

    var Delete = document.createElement('input');
    Delete.type = "button";
    Delete.setAttribute('onclick', 'Delete(this)');
    Delete.value = "Delete";
    td.appendChild(Delete);

  } else {

    var Save = document.createElement('input');
    Save.type = "button";
    Save.value = "Save";
    Save.setAttribute('onclick', 'Save(this)');
    td.appendChild(Save);
  }
}

function Add() {
  var p1 = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  const row1 = document.getElementById("row1");
  var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");



  //insert row beginning or end
  var element = document.createElement("tr");
  var table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
  table.appendChild(element);

  if (document.getElementById('input1').checked) {
    table.insertBefore(element, table.firstElementChild);

  } else if (document.getElementById('input2').checked) {
    table.lastElementChild.after(element);
  }

  var case1 = document.createElement("td");
  case1.innerHTML = p1;
  element.appendChild(case1);

  var case2 = document.createElement("td");
  element.appendChild(case2);
  createButtons(true, case2);
}


//delete:
function Delete(element) {
  element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode.parentNode);
}


//Edit:

function Edit(element) {

  const row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  const tdList = row.children;

  for (let index = 0; index < tdList.length - 1; index++) {
    const element = tdList[index];
    var str = element.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.id = "edit" + (index + 1).toString();
    input.value = str;
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
    element.appendChild(input);



  }
  const tdBtns = tdList[1];
  const btns = tdBtns.children;
  deleteButtons(btns, tdBtns);
  createButtons(false, tdBtns);
}


function Save(element) {
  const row = element.parentNode.parentNode;
  const tdList = row.children;

  /* const edit = [
      ['edit1'],
      ['edit2']
  ]; */

  const edit = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < tdList.length -1; index++) {
    if (!document.getElementById("edit" + (index + 1).toString())) {
       console.warn('no element with id ' + "edit" + (index + 1).toString());
       continue;
    }
    edit[index] = document.getElementById("edit" + (index + 1).toString()).value;
    if (edit[index] == "") {
      alert("You must not keep textboxes empty");
      var empty = true;
    }
  }

  if (!empty) {
    for (let index = 0; index < tdList.length - 1; index++) {
      tdList[index].removeChild(tdList[index].children[0]);
      var text = document.createTextNode(edit[index]);
      tdList[index].appendChild(text);
    }
    const tdBtns = tdList[1];
    const btns = tdBtns.children;
    deleteButtons(btns, tdBtns);
    createButtons(true, tdBtns);

  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Table</h1>
<div id="principal">
  <div id="cntr"><input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Element to add.">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="Add()"><br><br></div>
  <form id="frm">
    Add :
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input1"> at the beginning
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="input2"> at the end
  </form><br>
  <table id="MyTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="row1">
        <td id="name_row1">Element 1 </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" onclick="Edit(this)">
          <input type="button" value="Supprimer" onclick="Delete(this)">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```